# Using grep; how do I show the Nth occurence of a pattern?

Tags: linux, grep, text-editing, text-manipulation

Using `grep`; how do I show the ***<sup>N</sup>**th* occurence of a pattern?

For instance; `man sh |grep -A3 -- '-c'` will return several matches.

I might want to isolate the ***3**rd* occurrence only, so that it shows:

```
--
    -c  Read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the standard input.  Special parameter 0
        will be set from the command_name operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the
        remaining argument operands.
--
```

Answer (score 2):

The occurrence that you want is not the *second* occurrence; it is the *third*.  To get the third occurrence of `-c` with three lines of context:

```
$ man sh | awk '/-c/{n++; if (n==3)f=3;} f{print;f--;}'
           -c               Read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the standard input.  Special param‐
                            eter 0 will be set from the command_name operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)
                            set from the remaining argument operands.
```

#### How it works

awk implicitly reads its input line by line.  This script uses two variables.  `n` keeps track of how many times we have seen `-c`.  `f` keeps track of how many lines we are supposed to print.

- `/-c/{n++; if (n==3)f=3;}`

  If we reach a  line containing `-c`, then increment the count `n` by one.  If `n` is three, then set `f` to three.
- `f{print;f--;}`

  If `f` is nonzero, then print the line and decrement `f`.

#### Alternative solution

```
$ man sh | grep -A3 -m3 -- -c | tail -n4
           -c               Read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the standard input.  Special param‐
                            eter 0 will be set from the command_name operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)
                            set from the remaining argument operands.
```

The `-m3` option tells grep to return only the first three matches.  `tail -n4` returns the last four lines from among those matches.  If the second and third match to `-c` were within the context number of lines, though, this output may not be what you want.